# The <div> element has a margin even though the "margin: 0px;" style is applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started off by creating a `<div>` called `snake-container`, which contains the division tiles, which is 500x500px. I then used a for loop in Javascript to put a 25x25px grid of 20x20px `<div>`s with black backgrounds. However, instead of creating a grid like I wanted it created a long column of 625 `<div>`s. It turns out each `<div>` has a weird margin that stretches all the way from left to right within the `.tiles` `<div>`. I've set everything to 0 px margin, but these weird row-like margins remain. Why is this happening?

Here's the code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="snake-container">
            <div id="tiles">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
            const tile = document.createElement("div");
            tile.classList.add("tile");
            document.getElementById("tiles").appendChild(tile);
        }
    </script>
    
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #snake-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        #tiles {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .tile {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: The default behavior of div is such that it will occupy the maximum horizontal space. Same thing with any element that has display:block as the default, I think.
Are you trying to put div next to each other horizontally? Try `.tile{ inline-block ; line-height: 10px }` to see how much difference from what you want (not a final answer yet, I think it's better to use a grid).

Comment: @qrsngky This works for my purposes. Thanks a lot! Keep in mind this isn't a serious project, I'm just trying to throw something together and see what happens, so I'll just take anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the space is that the `justify-content` property is assigned a `center` value. The image below shows the behavior of containers when the `justify-content` property is set to a `center` value.

[image]

The image below is a demonstration of the feature causing the gap in Chrome Dev Tools.

[image]

In the application below, the `justify-content` property in the `#snake-container` block has been removed.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

      #snake-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }

      #tiles {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .tile {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Snake</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="snake-container">
      <div id="tiles"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
      const tile = document.createElement("div");
      tile.classList.add("tile");
      document.getElementById("tiles").appendChild(tile);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

### References

- [MDN Web Docs - justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)